# ¿Cómo añadir a una columna de una DataTable gestionada del lado del servidor (ServerSide) un botón que abra un modal para editar?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, server-side-rendering, server-side

Estoy trabajando con PHP e implementé una DataTable para mostrar los datos contenidos en las distintas tablas de mi base de datos; al estar manejando registros que ahondan en las 6 cifras, me vi en la obligación de utilizar la gestión de datos del lado del servidor (ServerSide) para evitar el tiempo extendido de carga. Al momento de implementarlo todo salió bien (utilicé la clase SSP), a excepción de que no logro definir cómo añadir los botones de edición y eliminación dentro de la columna **Opciones**. La estructura es al siguiente:

| Nombre | Puesto | Opciones |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Juan | Gerente |  |
| María | Supervisora |  |

HTML:

```
      <table id="usuarios" class="display">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>NO. EMPLEADO</th>
            <th>FECHA INICIAL</th>
            <th>FECHA FINAL</th>
            <th>ASUNTO</th>
            <th>AUTORIZACIÓN</th>
            <th>OPCIONES</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>NO. EMPLEADO</th>
            <th>FECHA INICIAL</th>
            <th>FECHA FINAL</th>
            <th>ASUNTO</th>
            <th>AUTORIZACIÓN</th>
            <th>OPCIONES</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

JavaScript (la función *createManageBtn()* es un intento fallido de implementar el botón):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#usuarios').DataTable( {
        'language': 
        {
            'url': 'vistas/plugins/datatables-language/spanish.json'
        },
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': '/ajax/permisos.ajax.php',
        "columnDefs": [{"render": createManageBtn, "data": null, "targets": [2]}]        
    });
});

function createManageBtn() 
{
    return 
    '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnEditar" id="11590" tabla="usuarios">
      <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>
     </button>';
}
```

AJAX:

```
<?php

$dbDetails = array( 
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'user' => 'root', 
    'pass' => '', 
    'db'   => 'pos' 
); 
 
$table = 'usuarios'; 
 
$primaryKey = 'id'; 
 
$columns = array( 
    array( 'db' => 'nombre', 'dt' => 0 ), 
    array( 'db' => 'puesto','dt' => 1 ), 
); 
  
require 'ssp/ssp.php'; 
 
echo json_encode( 
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) 
);
```

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te voy a mostrar un ejemplo completo que da la siguiente salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código html:

```
<!-- Default box -->
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h4 class="box-title">
                Listado de Usuarios de {{ estructura.title }} <a id="lnkActualizarDataTables" class="lnkCursorPuntero" data-src="{{ path('usuario_DTableListadoUsuariosNodo', {'estructuraId':estructura.idPublico|uuid_encode }) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Volver a cargar la lista de usuarios"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <label>Ver todos&nbsp;</label><input type="checkbox" id="chkVerTodos" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="tablaDatos" class="table table-condensed table-hover" style="width: 100%;" data-src="{{ path('usuario_DTableListadoUsuariosNodo', {'estructuraId':estructura.idPublico|uuid_encode}) }}" data-src-nuevo="{{ path('usuario_registrar', {'nodoId':estructura.idPublico|uuid_encode}) }}">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-primary">
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 4%;">No</th>
                                    <th style="width: 30%;">Nombre y Apellidos</th>
                                    <th style="width: 15%;">Identificador</th>
                                    <th>Rol</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">Estatus</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">Editar</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" style="width: 5%;">Eliminar</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead> 
                            <tbody></tbody>                
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cóigo javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _tablaDatosElement = $('#tablaDatos');
    var _dtAPI = $(_tablaDatosElement)
            .on('draw.dt', function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
            })
            .on('preXhr.dt', function (e, settings, data) {
                data.verTodos = $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked') ? true : false;
                data.columns = [];
            })
            .on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
                if (xhr.status === 401) {
                    window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                }
            })
            .DataTable({
                "sDom": " <'row'<'#btnAdd.col-sm-2'><'col-sm-2'l><'col-sm-8'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-1'i><'col-sm-11'p>>",
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "numero", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "nombre", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "identificador", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "rol", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "status", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "editar_link", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"data": "eliminar_link", "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {"name": "numero", "targets": 0, "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"name": "nombre", "targets": 1, "orderable": false, "searchable": false, },
                    {"name": "identificador", "targets": 2, "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {"name": "rol", "targets": 3, "searchable": false, "orderable": false},
                    {
                        "name": "status",
                        "targets": 4,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data === 'enabled') {
                                return '<span class="label label-success">Habilitado</span>';
                            } else if (data === 'disabled') {
                                return '<span class="label label-warning">Deshabilitado</span>';
                            } else if (data === 'baja') {
                                return '<span class="label label-danger">Baja</span>';
                            } else {
                                return '<span class="label label-warning">Desconocido</span>';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "editar_link",
                        "targets": 5,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEditar btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Editar usuario"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Editar</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEditar btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-flat disabled" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Editar usuario"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Editar</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "eliminar_link",
                        "targets": 6,
                        "render": function (data, type, full) {
                            if (data.enabled === true) {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEliminar btn btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Eliminar usuario"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a>';
                            } else {
                                return '<a class="dtBtnEliminar btn btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-flat disabled" data-src="' + data.src + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Eliminar usuario"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>&nbsp;Eliminar</a>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": $(_tablaDatosElement).data('src'),
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "searchDelay": 1000,
                "paging": true,
                "info": true,
                "searching": true,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "order": false,
                "autoWidth": true,
                "FixedHeader": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por p&aacute;gina",
                    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                    "infoEmpty": "No se encontraron registros",
                    "emptyTable": "No hay registros disponibles",
                    "infoFiltered": "(filtrados de _MAX_ registros totales)",
                    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "processing": "Cargando...",
                    "search": "Buscar por Nombre o Identificador:",
                    "paginate": {
                        "first": "Primera",
                        "last": "&Uacute;ltima",
                        "next": "Siguiente",
                        "previous": "Anterior"
                    }
                },
                "stateSave": true,
                "stateDuration": 60 * 60 * 24,
                "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                    try {
                        data.verTodos = $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked');
                        localStorage.setItem('DTusuarios', JSON.stringify(data));
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('on stateSaveCallback ' + e.message);
                    }
                },
                "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
                    try {
                        var estado = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DTusuarios'));
                        if (estado !== null) {
                            $('#chkVerTodos').prop('checked', estado.verTodos);
                        }

                        return estado;
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log('on stateLoadCallback ' + e.message);
                    }
                }
            });
    $('#btnAdd').html('<a id="lnkRegistrarUsuario" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-flat" data-src="' + _tablaDatosElement.data("src-nuevo") + '" data-cerrar-dialogo="1" original-title="Registrar usuario">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;Nuevo</a>');
    $('#lnkActualizarDataTables').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        actualizarDataTable(_dtAPI, false);
    });
    $('#lnkRegistrarUsuario').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        agregarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI, true);
    });
    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnEliminar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        eliminarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });
    $(_tablaDatosElement).find('tbody').on('click', 'a.dtBtnEditar', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var elemento = $(this);
        editarRegistro(elemento, _dtAPI);
    });
    $('#chkVerTodos').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue',
    }).on('ifChanged', function (e) {
        actualizarDataTable(_dtAPI, false);
    });
});
```

Controlador (server side):

```
public function DTableUsuariosNodoAction(Request $request, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder) {
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
            if (!$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(array('ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN', 'ROLE_ESP_AS'))) {
                return new Response("Acceso denegado !!!", 403);
            }
            $nodoId = $uuidEncoder->decode($request->get('estructuraId'));
            $draw = \intval($request->request->get('draw'));
            $columns = $request->request->get('columns');
            $start = \intval($request->request->get('start'));
            $length = \intval($request->request->get('length', $this->container->getParameter('resultados_por_pagina')));
            $filtro = $request->request->get('search');
            $verTodos = $request->request->getBoolean('verTodos', false);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $nodo = $em->getRepository(\AppBundle\Entity\EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($nodoId);
            if (is_null($nodo)) {
                return new Response("No se encontró la estructura seleccionada!!!", 404);
            }

            $resultado = $em->getRepository(Usuario::class)->usuariosPorEstructuraDTable($nodo, $start, $length, $verTodos, $filtroNombre = $filtro['value']);
            $data = array();
            $numero = $start + 1;
            foreach ($resultado['results'] as $usuario) {
                $status = "enabled";
                if ($usuario->getActivo() === false) {
                    if (!is_null($usuario->getDeletedAt())) {
                        $status = "baja";
                    } else {
                        $status = "disabled";
                    }
                }
                $data[] = array(
                    'DT_RowId' => $uuidEncoder->encode($usuario->getIdPublico()),
                    'numero' => $numero,
                    'nombre' => $usuario->getNombreCompleto(),
                    'identificador' => $usuario->getUsername(),
                    'rol' => $usuario->getRol()->getNombreRol(),
                    'status' => $status,
                    'editar_link' => array(
                        'src' => $this->generateUrl('usuario_editar', array('id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($usuario->getIdPublico()))),
                        'enabled' => ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(array('ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN', 'ROLE_ESP_AS')) && $status !== "baja")
                    ),
                    'eliminar_link' => array(
                        'src' => $this->generateUrl('usuario_eliminar', array('id' => $uuidEncoder->encode($usuario->getIdPublico()))),
                        'enabled' => ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted(array('ROLE_ESP_NAC', 'ROLE_ESP_PROV', 'ROLE_ESP_MUN', 'ROLE_ESP_AS')) && $status !== "baja")
                    ),
                );
                $numero += 1;
            }
            $dataRespuesta = array(
                'draw' => $draw,
                'recordsTotal' => $resultado['totalResults'],
                'recordsFiltered' => $resultado['countResults'],
                'data' => $data
            );
            return new JsonResponse($dataRespuesta);
        } else {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado.");
        }
    }
```

la definición de la función que obtiene los datos desde la Base de datos (fíjate para qué tengas una idea de cómo se completan las consultas teniendo en cuenta un posible filtro). A este ejemplo le falta ordenar por determinadas columnas, realmente no lo necesito en mi caso pero este método te va a dar un norte de cómo se realiza.

```
public function usuariosPorEstructuraDTable(EstructuraOrganizativa $estructura, $start, $length, $verTodos, $filtroNombre = '') {
        $tipoEstructuraId = $estructura->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId();

        $mainQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $countQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $totalResultsQuery = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery();
        $mainDql = "SELECT u FROM AppBundle:Usuario u JOIN u.rol r JOIN u.estructuraOrganizativa nodo WHERE nodo.id = :estructuraId";
        $countDql = "SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM AppBundle:Usuario u JOIN u.rol r JOIN u.estructuraOrganizativa nodo WHERE nodo.id = :estructuraId";
        $totalResultDql = "SELECT COUNT(u.id) FROM AppBundle:Usuario u JOIN u.rol r JOIN u.estructuraOrganizativa nodo WHERE nodo.id = :estructuraId";


        if (!empty($filtroNombre)) {
            $mainDql .= " AND ((u.nombreCompleto LIKE :filtroNombre) OR (u.username LIKE :filtroNombre))";
            $countDql .= " AND ((u.nombreCompleto LIKE :filtroNombre) OR (u.username LIKE :filtroNombre))";
            $mainQuery->setParameter('filtroNombre', $filtroNombre . '%');
            $countQuery->setParameter('filtroNombre', $filtroNombre . '%');
        }

        if ($verTodos === true) {
            $filter = $this->getEntityManager()->getFilters()->enable('softdeleteable');
            $filter->disableForEntity(\AppBundle\Entity\Usuario::class);
        }

        $mainDql .= " ORDER BY u.id ASC";

        $mainQuery->setDQL($mainDql);
        $countQuery->setDql($countDql);
        $totalResultsQuery->setDql($totalResultDql);

        $mainQuery->useQueryCache(true);
        $countQuery->useQueryCache(true);
        $totalResultsQuery->useQueryCache(true);

        $mainQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());
        $countQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());
        $totalResultsQuery->setParameter('estructuraId', $estructura->getId());

        $mainQuery->setFirstResult($start);
        $mainQuery->setMaxResults($length);

        $resultados = $mainQuery->getResult();
        $countResults = $countQuery->getSingleScalarResult();
        $totalResults = $totalResultsQuery->getSingleScalarResult();

        $resultado = array("results" => $resultados, "countResults" => $countResults, "totalResults" => $totalResults);

        return $resultado;
    }
```

Revisa la definición de cada columna del Datatables, verás como se genera del lado del cliente un boton (en este caso una etiqueta a con estilo botón) y cómo se manejan los eventos click de esos botones; ahora bien, las url (direcciones) de los controladores que procesarán las acciones de esos botones, se dejan definidos en el `json` que retorna el servidor como parte del controller que genera el Datatables. Por último, el botón `Nuevo` se define como parte de la barra de herramientas(por así llamarle) del Datatables, personalizando la propiedad `**sDom**` del Datatables. La misma define qué partes se generarán.

Este Datatables tiene una particularidad: el estado del mismo se almacena en el localStorage del navegador del cliente, de manera tal que si el usuario abandona la vista y mas tarde vuelve al Datatables, mantendrá la última página de datos visitada, así como el posible filtro de la barra de búsqueda y si se mostraron o no los usuarios dados de baja o deshabilitados.

Answer (score 0):

por límites de caracteres en la respuesta agrego otra como continuidad de la anterior y para complementar.

Te voy a detallar la función javascript `editarRegistro`, la misma se encarga de cargar el formulario de edición en forma de diálogo modal. A la misma se le pasan dos argumentos: el elemento que llama a la función javascript y el datatables ya creado. Se ve un poco aterradora y la explico: El primer argumento, es el boton que editar, del mismo se toma la url del controlador que en primera instancia cargará el formulario html via ajax en el cuerpo del modal, y el segundo argumento, el datatables para poder refrescarlo y se vea el cambio realizado; aunque claro hay otras posibilidades como es sustituir todo el tbody del datatables, o modificar ciertas columnas, pero eso es más puntual porque esta función me sirve para editar registros que no están dentro de un datatables como tal.

```
function editarRegistro(elemento, dataTableActualizar = null) {
    var titulo = elemento.data('original-title');
    var url = elemento.data('src');
    var fila = elemento.parents('tr');
    Pace.track(function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
        }).done(function (data) {
            $(document.body).find('#modalCaptura').remove();
            $(document.body).append("<div id='modalCaptura' class='modal fade' tabindex='-1'  role='dialog'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header bg-primary'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Cerrar'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button><h5 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Editar registro</h5></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenedorForm' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-flat' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button><button id='btnSalvar' type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-flat'>Salvar</button></div></div></div></div>");
            if (titulo !== undefined) {
                $(".modal-title").html('<strong>' + titulo + '</strong>');
            }

            $("#contenedorForm").html(data);
            $('#modalCaptura').modal({
                keyboard: false,
                backdrop: 'static'
            }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dialogo = $(this);
                $('#contenedorForm form').on('submit', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
                $("#btnSalvar").on('click', function (evtBtn) {
                    evtBtn.preventDefault();
                    var btn = $(this);
                    if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                        Pace.track(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                dataType: 'json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: $("#modalCaptura").find("form").attr('action'),
                                data: $("#modalCaptura").find("form").serialize(),
                                beforeSend: function () {
                                    $(btn).addClass('disabled');
                                }
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                $(dialogo).modal('hide');
                                toastr.success(data.msg, '', {
                                    timeOut: 3000,
                                    preventDuplicates: false,
                                    positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                    progressBar: true,
                                    showDuration: 800,
                                    hideDuration: 1000,
                                    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                    showEasing: "swing",
                                    hideEasing: "linear",
                                    showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                    hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                                });
                                switch (data.operacion) {
                                    case 'sustituir_columnas':
                                    {
                                        /** 
                                         * Sustituir el contenido de cada columna, 
                                         * excepto la primera, es el numero de columna y no varIa durante la edicion.
                                         * */
                                        var contadorColumnas = data.data.length;
                                        for (i = 0; i < contadorColumnas; i++) {
                                            $(fila).find('td').eq(i + 1).html(data.data[i]);
                                        }
                                        if (data.colorearFila === true) {
                                            $(fila).addClass('danger');
                                        } else if (data.colorearFila === false) {
                                            $(fila).removeClass('danger');
                                        }

                                        $(fila).animate({opacity: '0'}, 550).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'}, 400).delay(100).animate({opacity: '0'}, 500).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'}, 400).delay(100).animate({opacity: '0'}, 500).delay(100).animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case 'sustituir_filas':
                                    {
                                        /**
                                         * Sustituye todas las filas del tbody de #tablaDatos
                                         **/
                                        $('#vistas').find('#tablaDatos tbody').html(data.data);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case 'sustituir_vista':
                                    {
                                        /**
                                         * sustituye todo el contenido de la vista 
                                         **/
                                        $('#vistas').html(data.data);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case 'eliminar_fila':
                                    {
                                        $(fila).remove();
                                        var i = 1;
                                        $('#vistas').find('#tablaDatos > tbody > tr').each(function () {
                                            $(this).find('td:first').text(i++);
                                        });
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    case 'actualizar_datatables':
                                    {
                                        if (dataTableActualizar !== null) {
                                            dataTableActualizar.ajax.reload(null, false);
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                // generar los tooltips de los elementos agregados por la peticion ajax
                                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                    toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", 'Error ' + jqXHR.status, {
                                        timeOut: 2500,
                                        preventDuplicates: false,
                                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                        onHidden: function () {
                                            window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 406) {
                                    $(dialogo).find('#contenedorForm').html(jqXHR.responseText);
                                } else {
                                    toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, 'Error ' + jqXHR.status, {
                                        timeOut: 3000,
                                        preventDuplicates: false,
                                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                        progressBar: true,
                                        showDuration: 800,
                                        hideDuration: 1000,
                                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                        showEasing: "swing",
                                        hideEasing: "linear",
                                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                                    });
                                }
                            }).always(function () {
                                $(btn).removeClass('disabled');
                            });
                            ;
                        });
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document.body).find("div[class='datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu']").remove();
                $(document.body).find('#modalCaptura').remove();

            });
        }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", 'Error ' + jqXHR.status, {
                    timeOut: 2500,
                    preventDuplicates: false,
                    positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                    onHidden: function () {
                        window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, 'Error ' + jqXHR.status, {
                    timeOut: 3000,
                    preventDuplicates: false,
                    positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                    progressBar: true,
                    showDuration: 800,
                    hideDuration: 1000,
                    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                    showEasing: "swing",
                    hideEasing: "linear",
                    showMethod: "fadeIn",
                    hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```